# MVC and angularJs routing conflict

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC application I have a home controller and an index method in it. I have set the index methods as the default route in the RouteConfig file.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I'm using Angular JS in my application. I have defined a service and calling an action 'Clusters' in the home controller using $http.

```
app.service('homeService', function ($http) {

    this.getClusters = function () {
        var promise = $http.get("Clusters");
        return promise;
    };
});
```

When I run the project and go to the default url [http://localhost:56698/] then http://localhost:56698/Clusters 404 not found exception occurred. But it is working if the url is http://localhost:56698/Home/Index. So my Angular js services are not working in the default url. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a problem with your javascript reference.
you should use relative referencing like this :

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/angular.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or you should change your clusters calling:( I assumed that your javascript code is located in your view)

```
 this.getClusters = function () {
    var promise = $http.get('@Url.action(Clusters,Your controller name)');
    return promise;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it is not worked. Reference to angular script is working in both url. But the url path 'Cluster' couldn't find in the default url [http://localhost:56698/].

Comment: @NOBLEM.O.:your welcome. I edited my answer base on your comment. please inform me if the new answer didn't work out.

Comment: Thank you pooria taghizadeh. The script is not in view file. So I cannot use @Url helper. I specified the controller name/action name in my script as you suggested. It worked. Thank you.

Comment: @NOBLEM.O. your welcome my friend. It was my pleasured to help you